# Search query for multiple search terms

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm running Laravel 5 and have built a small search function:

```
    $q = Input::get('q');
    $search_terms = explode(' ', $q);

    $user_query = User::select();
    $news_query = Article::select();
    foreach ($search_terms as $term) {
        $user_query->where('username', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
        $news_query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
    }
    $user_results = $user_query->get();
    $news_results = $news_query->get();


    return view('search', ['q' => $q, 'user_results' => $user_results, 'news_results' => $news_results]);
```

It works for one search term, but doesn't quite work with multiple words.

Example:

- "boss" returns users and news items that contain "boss"
- "boss man" returns users and news items that contain "boss"
- "man boss" returns users and news items that contain "man"

How can I make adjustments so it will return users and news items that contain "boss" or "man" ?

Comment: try to echo the sql query and run it in your SQL ide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, your query is executed using `and` statements, so MySQL is looking for usernames consisting of both `boss` and `man`.

You can change to `orWhere()` and it should work right away. Here's a quick experiment I did in Tinker using your code:

```
$terms = explode(' ', 'c a');
$user_query = User::select();
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $user_query->orWhere('username', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
}
$user_results = $user_query->get();
$user_results->toArray();

// array(
//   0 => array(
//     'id' => 2,
//     'username' => 'christopher',
//     'created_at' => '2014-04-27 18:41:56',
//     'updated_at' => '2014-11-07 13:42:58',
//     'remember_token' => NULL
//   ),
//   1 => array(
//     'id' => 4,
//     'username' => 'Kalle',
//     'created_at' => '2014-11-07 13:42:55',
//     'updated_at' => '2014-11-07 13:42:55',
//     'remember_token' => NULL
//   )
// )
```